# What is the meaning of reputation?

Tags: discussion

Is it really necessary? I just want to know how a user should interpret my reputation and the reputations of my peers.

Do not mark is a duplicated, as is intended to ask if is really necessary according to the meaning. I think that we still are discussing this....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation: "Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; ..." Imho, it's extraordinarily rough.

Comment: And while voting on meta has nearly no effect at all on users, remember that the standard reasons still apply: "This question does not show any research effort" fits perfectly.

Comment: MMMM... you know @Deduplicator.. funny fact : sometimes my reputation goes up and i just didn't anything.. so... are you saying that the the community trusts me every day a little more?

Comment: Well, reputation is a thoroughly imperfect metric. That's just the nature of the beast.

Comment: Interesting.. thanks for the time and answer @Deduplicator. Please don't judge me quickly.. my intention was to ask this, and i think i am at the right place to do it. If you don't want to be part, you just  can leave. I just... want to clear my mind a little and gather some information about what real users things about their reputation.

Comment: @Victor: with time, if more people say that your contributions have been helpful, we can indeed trust you more. That's the power of multiple people validating that you contributed something of value.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @MartijnPieters. Other funny fact : Some times when i really try to help, i get downvoted and me reputation get's down and some other times the reputation get's up, and i just do nothing.. we could argue that stackoverflow reputation is some how very similiar to real-life reputation. It really means nothing until you meet and work the person.

Comment: @Victor I think with the up and downvotes you are looking too much at the details. I tend to look at where the downvotes and (or where I lose rep through retracted acceptance, non-accepted suggested edit) as to know if I could have done something better, or misread the question (in that case an accepted other answer often gives a clue). Don't worry too much about it, look at the big picture and the total score per day, or better per week.

Comment: My experience is similar to yours. As has already been said "its an imperfect metric". Sometimes I'll work for weeks on researching and testing code for an answer only to have it downvoted by revenge downvoters. My largest number of points came from (in my view) my worst posting which didn't even compile or solve the problem. Sometimes its just random - but thatss how it is....

Comment: @Anthon and BrianTompseet Thanks for the comments. I share you point of view. What i am really to try to clarify to myself, is that currently reputation system isn't well.. as it is well in really life too (that the root of the problem...) it is an inaccurate measure. This post, as many others, open the ways to ask the community "if we all have the same felling about rep, why we don't propose something?"....

Comment: @hichris123 i think you are right. Thanks for the attention. BTW : funny fact again.. .why if the other user is doing the same question he gets upvoted and i gets downvoted? I am being ugly or rude to anyone?..

Comment: @GrantWinney my solution is to dismiss reputation.  And to enable downvote only if a comment is present. What do you think about it? could you send my proposal to someone that cares about it?

Comment: Well Grant as i see... the "reputation system" is a side-effect of the scoring that users grants to the posts according to his utility (considering that the utility can be measured in absolute terms). It is good to raise up the other that f was helpful or more persons rather than those who wheren't so useful.. I agree with scoring in order to allow us to sort and organize the post, but i don't agree to mix that with reputation. Also, i find without sense, downvotes do not come with a comment.. the most value thing.

Comment: a downvote **is** a comment - hover over the up/dn buttons.  It is a critique of the Q or A not your value as a human being

Comment: @Plutonix downvote is not comment....c'mon Downvote is one thing and comment is another...

Comment: i think.. this community has a lot of human still to do. I would love to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is only what you and other agree upon that it is, and StackOverflow help (IIRC) defines it as a measure of trust worthiness. As with any measure there are measurement errors. Some have high reputation undeserved (e.g. based on a single very popular question) and others give extremely good answers on old question regarding unpopular subjects and don't reach the rep necessary to comment.

StackOverflow needs some way to select who has what rights to do the various things that need doing on the site (because of the self-moderation) and rep is it. I would not ask if it is good or bad, I would ask if it works in general, motivates enough people to participate to keep a healthy site and just go with it until someone comes up with a better selection procedure.

Comment: I will just copy pasted my comment above in order to make sure you read it Anthon and Plutonix.
 
I agree with scoring in order to allow us to sort and organize the posts, but i don't agree to mix that with reputation. They are complete different thing.. one attach to the community the other to the person... if you would to classify the persons by reputation, i suggest that you judge then by other skill : the will to learn and to share. If the community knows that we have a "flaw here" (reputations can be misleading).. why not correct it?

Comment: Can we just agree on "reputations can be misleading"?

Comment: The high reputation based on single question, answer could be improved using a logarithmic reputation calclulation starting after x votes `rep = first x votes + ln(total-numer-of-votes-first x votes)`
I wonder if it would be good to create a SO subset of premium questions and answer which is hosted seperately.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree.. i think that is no way to measure a concept  so volatile such as "reputation". I believe it is wrong to mix post ranking system with reputation.

Comment: Well nobodies really say something about if the stackoverflow reputation can be misleading or not... i assume the silent will fill the space with what we wanna believe. The important thing.. i already express myself. Have good day lads.